# Drilling hole for latch bolt with regular tools?

Tags: wood, doors, drill

I need to drill the hole where the door latch will go, but I don't have a specialized tool for this. I only have a few spade bits (plus some regular bits), but they're all smaller than the latch.

What tools can I use to drill that hole in the door?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The question isn't clear. What's the problem with your spade bits? Properly aligned and supported, they'd do fine.

Answer (score 4):

For that you will want the right bit. Using the wrong size, and trying to ream it out the full depth you need, can easily ruin the door. Even with experience, it would be difficult. An installer would know not to try what you are asking. Get the right size bit. A cheap spade/paddle bit will do fine.

Comment: Or in short, the right bits are cheaper than a new door.